# Unable to install PHP CodeSniffer in wamp or xampp in windows 10 system

Tags: php, pear, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I am trying to install code sniffer in my localhost but unable to install it.

**System: Windows 10**

**PHP: PHP 5.4+**

I have tried below methods.

1. Open  command prompt with administrative permissions (select “run as administrator “)
2. Go to your php install directory. For example : \wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12
3. Run this command "**pear install PHP_CodeSniffer**" OR "**pear install --alldeps PHP_CodeSniffer**"

> **Error:**
>
> D:\Projects\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
> No releases available for package "pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer"
> install failed

4. Then run this command "**pear clear-cache**" and this also giving error like,

> **Error:**
>
> D:\Projects\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>pear clear-cache
> C:\Users\pcs9\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache does not exist or is not a directory

I have to use code sniffer "phpcs" and "phpcbf" but without install PHP_CodeSniffer its not worked.

Please help to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure why PEAR is not working for you on windows (I just tried an install of macOS and it is working) but I wanted to point out that you can also run PHP_CodeSniffer using the PHAR files, or from a Composer install, or straight from a Git clone. If you want to try that out to see if PHPCS is working, the instructions are here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer#installation

Comment: Ok, Thank you... Actually PEAR is working fine but I am not able to install PHP_CodeSniffer

Answer (score 1):

PEAR is not the best way to install PHP packages nowadays.

**You could try [Composer](https://getcomposer.org):**

```
composer require squizlabs/php_codesniffer --dev
```

Comment: From where to run this?

Comment: From your project directory